# Plane Geometry Pic

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

So I was given this by a student at my job, I tried setting up a system using a couple right triangles but I have like 4 unknowns and I doubt the teacher wants them to do a 4 by 4? I know I am totally brain farting and am forgetting one piece of information.

Also it didn't specify the point is the CENTER, but IF it were the center, would that imply $x = 4$?

and it looks like the figure inside the circle is a kite? thanks for any help and sorry for my huge brain fart. I am currently preparing for the GRE subject and I feel stupid when I get stuck here.

ALSO, they gave me that the answer is $x = 2$. I don't like working backwards though knowing the answer specially since I am teaching it to a high school student.

Comment: If the point were the center, the answer would be $x=4$, yes.

Comment: cool thanks that's what I thought, given the perpendicularness goin on.

Comment: Yeah, although if it's not known to be the center, you can pick a point arbitrarily far along the diameter bisecting the angles between the two chords and drop perpendiculars to get $x$ to be pretty much anything.

Comment: The answer is $x=2$, because $4$ is the whole chord.

Comment: 4 was not given to be the whole chord. it was that segment of the chord, the chords length is $x + 4$

Answer (score 3):

If the point were the center, then since a perpendicular from the center of a circle to a chord always bisects the chord, $x=4$.

If the point were not the center, and was an arbitrary point inside the circle, then $x$ could be anything, and the diagram would still be possible.

Comment: Ok so I need more info to get a specific $x$ value? I would need an angle wouldn't I ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not even an angle would suffice (at least, not the angle between the two $x$s)

Comment: Thanks so much!